# Variable assignment (model creation) seems to stop code flow in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Edit: Tried making the Account model the long way, `$account = new Account()...`, assigning each column (property) and calling save. I found out the line `new Account` causes the issue.

So I have this invokable controller for a route, if I put a `return 'test';` before the `Account::create` call it will return to my SPA frontend with 'test'.

If I put it after the `Account::create` my frontend receives a 200 but chrome developer tools reports `This request has no response data available.`, why is it not hitting my return?

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Onboarding;

use App\Models\Account;
use App\Models\Theme;
use App\Rules\MinDob;
use App\Models\Business;
use App\Models\Location;
use App\Models\AccountType;
use App\Models\Organisation;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\AccountStatus;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class BusinessController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function validationRules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'role' => 'required',
            'dob' => ['required', 'date', 'date_format:Y-m-d', 'before:-14 years'],
            'street_number' => 'sometimes|max:255',
            'route' => 'sometimes|max:255',
            'postal_town' => 'sometimes|max:255',
            'locality' => 'sometimes|max:255',
            'region' => 'sometimes|max:255',
            'country' => 'sometimes|max:255',
            'postal_code' => 'sometimes|max:255',
            'formatted' => 'required|max:255',
            'longitude' => 'required',
            'latitude' => 'required',
            'place_id' => 'required',
            'business_name' => 'required|string|min:2|max:255|unique:organisations,name',
            'url' => 'sometimes|url|active_url',
            'industry_id' => 'required|exists:industries,id',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * User education onboarding request.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        parent::__invoke($request);

        $request
            ->user()
            ->update([
                'name' => $request->get('name'),
                'onboarded' => true,
            ]);

        $request
            ->user()
            ->profile
            ->update([
                'role' => $request->get('role'),
                'dob' => $request->get('dob')
            ]);

        $organisation = Organisation::create([
            'name' => $request->get('business_name'),
            'slug' => $slug = str_slug($request->get('business_name')),
        ]);

        $organisation
            ->users()
            ->attach($request->user());

        $business = Business::firstOrCreate([
            'name' => $request->get('business_name')
        ]);

        Account::create([
                'slug' => $slug,
                'url' => $request->get('url', null),
                'industry_id' => $request->get('industry_id'),
                'business_id' => $business->id,
                'account_type_id' => AccountType::where('name', 'business')->first()->id,
                'theme_id' => Theme::first()->id,
                'account_status_id' => AccountStatus::where('name', 'pending')->first()->id,
            ]);

        return response(['message' => 'boom town bitch'], 200);

        $account->asStripeCustomer();

        $location = Location::firstOrCreate([
            'type' => 'home',
            'street_number' => $request->get('street_number'),
            'route' => $request->get('route'),
            'postal_town' => $request->get('postal_town'),
            'locality' => $request->get('locality'),
            'region' => $request->get('region'),
            'country' => $request->get('country'),
            'postal_code' => $request->get('postal_code'),
            'formatted' => $request->get('formatted'),
            'longitude' => $request->get('longitude'),
            'latitude' => $request->get('latitude'),
            'place_id' => $request->get('place_id')
        ]);

        $account
            ->locations()
            ->attach($location);

        return response()->json($account, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the logs for any errors?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't see anything in the logs.

Comment: Edit: Tried making the Account model the long way, `$account = new Account()...`, assigning each column (property) and calling save. I found out the line `new Account` causes the issue.

Comment: Okay, so its when I add the Billable trait to the account model.

Comment: Try running the code in `php artisan tinker` and see what errors you get, line by line.